# Playframework 2.1.2 how to prevent scala function calls on template load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, playframework, onclick

I have a number of Scala function calls in my template file, unfortunately they are getting automatically called during template loading for some reason. How can I prevent those from being called?

My intention is they are called only after certain click events. And I would get a huge performance increase during template load (26s vs 3s).

I have a DataLoader Java object, which is being called from template and does the reading of values from database. The relevant parts of DataLoader:

```
public void SetAllowLoading() {
    System.out.println("DataLoader SetAllowLoading > ");
    allowLoading = 1;
}

public void SetDisAllowLoading() {
    allowLoading = 0;
}

public void debugdebug(String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}

public List<Double> loadAreaLengthData() {
    List<Double> areaLengthArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
    System.out.println("DataLoader OUT loadAreaLengthData > ");
    if (allowLoading > 0) {
        System.out.println("DataLoader IN loadAreaLengthData > ");
        areaLengthArray.add(Component.getPipeLenghtsAccordingToRelativeFloorAreaMeters(0, 11));
        areaLengthArray.add(Component.getPipeLenghtsAccordingToRelativeFloorAreaMeters(11, 21));
        areaLengthArray.add(Component.getPipeLenghtsAccordingToRelativeFloorAreaMeters(21, 31));
        areaLengthArray.add(Component.getPipeLenghtsAccordingToRelativeFloorAreaMeters(31, 41));
        areaLengthArray.add(Component.getPipeLenghtsAccordingToRelativeFloorAreaMeters(41, 51));
    }
    return areaLengthArray;
}
```

If loading is not allowed, the loading method doesn't read from database.

Then the necessary parts from template (pipeIndex.scala.html)

```
$("#info2").on("click", function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $("#info2").html('@Messages("consequence.floor") (m<sup>2</sup>/m)');
        @loader.debugdebug("debugFloorAreaDESELECT");
        deselectArea();               
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(".chartsarea").slideFadeToggle(function() {

            @loader.debugdebug("drawFloorAreaChart()");

            var sarea = new Array(); 
            var i = 0;
            var number = 0;
            @for(s <- loader.loadAreaLengthData) {
                number = Math.round(@s);
                if (!isNaN(number))
                    sarea[i] = Math.round(number / 1000);
                else
                    sarea[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
            var ticksArea = ["0-10", "10-20", "20-30", "30-40", "40-50"];
            areaObj = {
                // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
                animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
                seriesDefaults:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    pointLabels: { show: true }
                },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: ticksArea
                    }
                },
                highlighter: { show: false }
            }   
            plot3 = $.jqplot('chartarea', [sarea], areaObj);

            $("#info2").focus();
            $("#info2").html('@Messages("consequence.hide.floor")');
        });
    }
    return false;
});

function deselectArea() {
    $(".chartsarea").slideFadeToggle(function() {
        $("#info2").removeClass("selected");
    }); 
}
```

My question is how that "on" click handler is called automatically at every pageload? How can I prevent the calling during pageload?

I used for showing/hiding functionality the example at jsfiddle: [anotherjsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7pxU/) However I used multiple click handlers (here is shown only for info2 element). And I changed that jquery "live" event method to "on", because "live" is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right you are asking why the debug messages (e.g. `@loader.debugdebug("debugFloorAreaDESELECT");`) are getting called on each site load and not only on click..?

This is because Play templates are getting rendered on the server side, i.e. as soon as `template.render()` will get called in the controller. This affects all the the Scala parts in the template (i.e. everything starting with `@`)

If you would like to debug on the client side you could use JavaScripts `console.log()`

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm wondering (why not only on click?..) Is there a way to prevent/workaround that calling?

Comment: Btw. I got a response @playframework forums:
You'll need to use AJAX to compute those results later on.
My answer: I'll take a look at AJAX. Btw. are Playframework's asynchronous results and Websockets usable in this case? 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaAsync
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaWebSockets
If yes, which way (AJAX/async/webS) would be more easy implement?

Comment: Yes you will need to change your approach to an Ajax style, if you want to get the result only computed if the user actually clicks. Typically you would use Play's standard async actions and send and receive JSON to and from the client. I would suggest to read the respective parts of the docs open another question if you have trouble with specific points ;)

Comment: I'll check implementing it with Play's async actions. Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Although previous answer describes it I'll use a phrase which I repeated several times already:

> Play template is ***ServerSide*** technology, so it's rendered during Play pass (i.e. if your views will be cached for 1 month you will have 1 month old values in the view), ***JavaScript*** is **ClientSide**. That means - that you ***can't*** mix it like this.